# Functional programming language to pick when coming from ruby background

Tags: functional-programming

I have a mixed C++ and Ruby background. Are there any functional programming languages that bear some resemblance to either of these? I am trying to learn a functional programming language and a bit of syntactic or any other form of familiarity will no doubt help.

Comment: Maybe if you change the question to something like "I am trying to learn functional programming and would like to know where I can find comparisons of functional code. For example how would I do a tree traversal in a functional language. I currently know C++ and Ruby." Also tag the question with C++ and Ruby. My guess is that the words "bear some resemblance to either of these" leaves the question open for debate. Remove the ability to debate in the question and it might get the close removed. :)

Answer (score 3):

If you plan on just learning functional programming with the intent of learning other functional languages as needed, then **concentrate on a book about functional language that makes sense** and work on that than try and pick a language and find the learning material that teaches that language. Once you have one functional language down, the rest just keep getting easier. I started with F#, but picked up OCaml, LISP, and now ML along the way, all in less than a year. I still haven't reached Haskell, but someday should.

The reason I am suggesting you start by picking some learning material is that there are lots of good free books on the internet. I tend to find them as PDF files from the instructors account on the university they teach. Also most of the languages are free, but the power of the IDEs very from just syntax high-lighting to Eclipse and Visual Studio.

Since you will need to think in different concepts, don't carry the baggage of what you know about imperative or object-oriented programming with you. Start fresh and it will be easier.

Here is some more [advise](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/145874/49838).

As an example of the same concept but difference in syntax of languages see [fold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29), [map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_%28higher-order_function%29), [filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_%28higher-order_function%29) and [List comprehension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension).

Also to help you see a complete example (task) in multiple languages see [tree traversal](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#F.23), with the list of functional languages [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:Programming_paradigm/Functional) and the list of all tasks [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:Programming_Tasks).

As you can see the syntax varies greatly. I find the languages that added functional capability after the initial release, either by extending the language, adding libraries or using templates, to be some of the hardest to understand.